# any way to add windows notifications into my windows forms program

Tags: c#

new here and i was wondering if there was any way to add windows notifications into my windows forms program.

I am creating a small business database, to be used by fairly computer illiterate employees and am disabling windows explorer. I am adding my database to the windows registry to run at startup.

I just want to add some windows notifications such as networking info and date time.

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ they might be **computer illiterate**, but that does not preclude them from being able to read a time or, in the case of problems tell the support person if there is a red or green network icon in the corner of the screen

Comment: for when they call becuse vthe computer is out of cellular range and they need a clock

Comment: and thank you ubercoder

Comment: @Übercoder Yeah I know.. just kidding. btw what do you mean by windows notifications? Those balloons from the taskbar...?

Comment: yes specifically wifi and time